# ASP.NET Core Test xUnit Controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

this test always return null, and test always fail...but when i run the projet all works fine and return data normally, this project using RavenDB

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context = new AppDbContext();

    // GET: api/category
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Get(string id)
    {
        using (IAsyncDocumentSession session = _context.SessionAsync){
            var result = await session.LoadAsync<Category>(id);
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
}
```

and using xUnit to testing

```
 [Fact]
public async Task GetShouldReturnCategory()
{
    // Arrange
    var _categoryController = Substitute.For<CategoryController>();
    var category = CreateCategory();

    // Act
    var result = await _categoryController.Get(category.Result.Id);

    //Asserts here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on your question, ***system under test (SUT)*** is `CategoryController`. So, it doesn't make sense to mock `CategoryController`; instead, you want to mock `AppDbContext`.

If you want to unit test a controller, you should use ASP.NET Core's Dependency Inject, and inject its dependencies via constructor injection. In other words, you should not use ***new***.

Normally, we inject interface instead of concrete class, so that we can easily mock it.

*Your code is missing too many pieces, so I could only give you a directly. You want more detail you can look at this sample project at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Tests/Asp.Web.Tests/Controllers/LogsControllerTests.cs#L98) which uses NSubstitute and XUnit.*